# Error in python:TypeError

Tags: python

I am writing a function which takes a linked list as parameter and converts the values present in the nodes into a number Ex:`1->2->0` is a linked list it should return 120.
I tried in this way:

```
def list_to_number(head):
    a0 = head.value
    a1 = head.next
    a2 = a1.next
    num1 = (a0*100)
    num2 = (a1*10)
    num3 = a2
    num4 =sum(num1,num2,num3)
return num4
```

when I call it is showing an error:`TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'Node' and 'int'`.

Comment: Head.next is a node, not a number.

Comment: I think the question reflects that you need to spend more time on the concept of linked list.

Comment: yes it is anew concept which I have learnt recently in my course.So,some confusion persists.Thank you.@Ray

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't add a `Node` and an `int`. You need to get an integer value from each node:

```
def list_to_number(head):
    a0 = head.value
    a1 = head.next
    a2 = a1.next
    num1 = (a0*100)
    num2 = (a1.value*10)
    num3 = a2.value
    num4 =num1 + num2 + num3
return num4
```

Surely this code could be generalized to work with lists of any length. This generalization is left as an exersise for the reader.